# ListViewItems and preventing selection up and down with keyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a listview with some rows.

These rows contain a textbox.

I would like the listview to not change items when the user presses   <kbd>↑</kbd>   or   <kbd>↓</kbd>   on the keyboard if they are focused in a textbox.

Reasoning: One of the textboxes has a popup that shows some autocomplete results, it is common for the user to simply press   <kbd>↓</kbd>   on the keyboard to move through the suggestions. This is currently not working, as pressing   <kbd>↓</kbd>   is instead moving the users selection to the line below within the listview.

This is made harder due to the fact that winrt listviews do not have the PreviewKeyDown event.

Any ideas how i might be able to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe inheriting from ListView and overriding ProcessCmdKey (or OnKeyDown - I am not sure). In the method, you can set Handled or SuppressKeyPress property. You can also avoid calling base.ProcessCmdKey (or base.OnKeyDown) so the ListView won't process the key. Maybe this won't work because of the Win32 nature of ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution would be to check, in the keydown event, if the pop up is open, and, if it is, to change the pop up selection, instead.

Comment: That was my thinking, but how do i do the "instead" bit. I cant seem to find out where the event is firing that causes it to change line (and hence prevent it), i think it must be somewhere on the listview item?

Comment: The KeyEventArgs have a property called "SupressKeyPress". If you set this to 'true' when the key in question is the up or down arrow, then the line will not change in the listview. I tested it and it works.

Comment: I couldnt find the KeyEventArgs, but i did have access to KeyRoutedEventArgs which as a .handled property that when set to true would do what i wanted. Your suggestion helped me out.